# Delphi 2007: open another application in delphi and perform actions in that application

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

Would someone explain me which functions/procedures/functionalities I need of Delphi 2007 to open other applications and perform actions in those applications.

For example: I want Delphi to start a mathematical software application, export data to this application, perform some actions on that data and then retrieve the data from the application to Delphi.

At the moment, I'm not too familiar with the ShellExecute command.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question as asked can't really be answered; there is no *standard* way to automate another application. If the application supports COM automation, you can use it to work with the other application. Otherwise, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: ShellExecute only *starts* an application.

Answer (score 3):

Most applications do not support external automation, so your only option in those cases is to use `mouse_event()` and `keybd_event()` to simulate mouse/keyboard activity, and/or use `PostMessage()` and/or `SendMessage()` to send simulated messages directly to specific windows.  Automating an application that does not support automation is not trivial, depending on the complexity of its UI.